# How do I know which version of the .NET Framework my program is running on?

Tags: .net, clr

I have a program which I believe to be running in .NET 4.0, but I am unable to mixed-mode debug it (something new .net 4.0 for 64-bit application)

I wanted to confirm if I'm truly running in .NET 4.0 or is it running .NET 3.5

Is there a way to look in the memory space or something?

Comment: For the reason I mentioned, to rule out a build problem than rack my brain why I can't go from managed to unmanaged while debugging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different options are:

- Check the value of [Environment.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx)
- typeof (int).Assembly.GetName ().Version: this will give you the running mscorlib.dll assembly version.
- Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) if you can't change the code. Then check which version of mscorlib is loaded and from where.

Comment: Note though that this will return which version of the *CLR* that the program is running on. I can't verify it right now, but that should mean that it reports 2.0 both for apps running on .NET framework 2 and 3.5. .NET framework 4 comes with a new CLR, so that can be confirmed by checking the CLR version in use.

Comment: Is there a less invasive way of doing this? As in I do have sources, but I'll have to copy the entire tree down, and I'm roaming, not @ work so another solution would be helpful but I can try.

Comment: Yes, there is. Give me a minute to find the link.

Answer (score 1):

typeof(int).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion will give you the version of the mscorlib assembly loaded in your process.

Answer (score 1):

This returns the .Net runtime version as a string:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion()
```

You can also get the install directory as well:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory()
```

[goto msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeenvironment_methods.aspx)

Comment: I think both of these would return 2.0 for 2.0/3/3.5 Runtime because they all get installed under the 2.0 runtime.